# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.2.0.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, owin

I am trying to add OWIN JWT into webapi project using VS 2015. The reference shows `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens Version=5.3.0.0`. Below is the error when running. I could not find `5.2.0.0` in the source code.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/WebApi/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\WebApi\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 7):

First, you should understand that the exception occurred is not restricted to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens assembly, nor the Visual Studio Version. the problem is popular with the assembly referencing.

the popular reason is: you are referencing in the project to a version different than in the "DLL" package used in the execution (bin folder). However, I think this farther than getting happened manually.

1- I can guess based on the assembly name. that you have more than one project in your solution and you lastly installed the assembly using NuGet with a version higher than in other projects (of course using NuGet )

Try to verify the installed package in all your projects and update all of them to the latest one Version=5.3.0.0.

Another potential reason is: this package requires the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging 
try to do the same operation explained above in point 1.

Answer (score -1):

I removed all packages in solution that related *.Owin and install same version again.

Comment: I think for your comment to be useful you should describe more about how they were updated and how others can replicate your success.

Comment: @JT Actually all the thing I did was that, no more no less.