# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens problem

Tags: c#, jwt

I am trying to verify users with a JWT token. The code I used below works perfectly fine in a console application. But when I want to apply it in my Azure function it gives me the error:

`Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`

I do have one other Azure function in my solution but it doesn't use this NuGet package. I already took a look at this link:

[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341678/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-version-5-2-0-0)

I can't get anything out of that. So what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```cs
string key = "";
var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

var header = new JwtHeader(credentials);

var payload = new JwtPayload
{
    { "some ", "hello "},
    { "scope", "http://dummy.com/"},
};

var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var tokenString = handler.WriteToken(secToken);

var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenString);

log.LogInformation(token.ToString());
```

Comment: There's little point in looking at your code if you can't load the library, "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens". Your code might be fine. The question you referenced is about solving that problem which won't just go away if you ignore it.

Comment: Can you post complete stack trace of the error? This error also occurs if there is a problem with dependent libraries.

Comment: @stackunderflow `Executed login (Failed, Id=ac3f0995-cc77-48b3-acb1-8d787bb7e4e9, Duration=362ms)
[2021-03-03T07:15:59.197Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: login. DataEndpoint: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=6.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. System couldn't find specified file.`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved it by adding a line of code in the .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Explanation: https://bryanknox.github.io/2022/07/15/functionsskipcleanoutput-and-functionspreserveddependencies.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem not when running in development, but on deployed projects. This did not relate to Azure project, but to a web application deployed onto a remote windows web server

I took these steps to resolve it:

1. Get the files names of the DLLs from references
2. Find these DLLS in the packages subfolder of your vs project.
3. Make sure you have the right version for your .net framework version
4. Copy the DLLs to a folder, we called it "deployments"
5. Remove the Nuget packages
6. Reference the DLLs directly with copylocal=true

You may or may not need to add the DLLs to the bin folder in your deployment package. The packages we needed are shown below

[image: Packages needed]

Answer (score 0):

I've had a little different scenario: my error was NOT coming from an Azure Function but from a test project.

After some reading and seeing [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/50943), I've added the NuGet package below and it is working now

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35636883)