# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens - problem

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-6.0

Update:

I found that installing the Nuget package `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Token` gave me the same version everywhere.
Now, it runs but gives me a new error, this time runtime error:

```
The type initializer for System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions
 threw an exception.

at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions.get_Serializer()
```

Looking at that I found suggestions to use an older version of `Newtonsoft.Json` but that did not help, using 10-13.
Now I am stuck here.

*Original post:*

I am working on an Web API application, developed in DotNet 6, that is used in 3 different places, where one for development only. They are all on the same server.

However, only one work, while the others give this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, 
Version=6.29.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have narrowed the question to this line creating `JwtHeader`:

```
string key = "123456789..."
var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey,
   SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
// this line causes load of the DLL which causes the error:
JwtHeader header = new JwtHeader(credentials); // this line is the first to cause this.
```

The error started, when a JWT token check was added to another file.
Using the version before this works, no error.

Now, keep in mind, that the error happens while loading, not in execution.

When looking at the net, I found this among other pages suggesting the same solution:
[Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66399294/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-problem)
Which suggest to add this to the .csproj  file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, this does not change my situation. I still get the error in 2 of 3 places.

What could this be?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add  the different dll to different folder and add the message to web.config file.If the dll publicKeyToken are the same,you need to set just like that(use log4net.dll as example)

```
  <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
      <codeBase version="1.2.13.0" href="bin\log4netdll\1_2_13\log4net.dll" />
      <codeBase version="1.2.9.0" href="bin\log4netdll\1_2_9\log4net.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

If the dll publicKeyToken are not the  same,you need to set just like that:(use log4net.dll as example)

```
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
      <codeBase version="1.2.13.0" href="bin\log4netdll\1_2_13\log4net.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="b32731d11ce58905" />
      <codeBase version="1.2.9.0" href="bin\log4netdll\1_2_9\log4net.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

From above, my problem was in Nuget packages

I found that installing the Nuget package `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Token` gave me the same version everywhere. Next I got this time runtime error:

```
The type initializer for System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions
         threw an exception.
...
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions.get_Serializer()
```

Looking at that I found suggestions to use an older version of `Newtonsoft.Json` but that did not help, using 10-13. That did not help.

Then I found
[Error generating JWT token during ASP.NET Core Web API authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098132/error-generating-jwt-token-during-asp-net-core-web-api-authorization)

Telling me I need another Nuget package: `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

It works now